# Python pandas difflib throws; "list index out of range" Error

Tags: python, pandas

Why does difflib.get_close_matches throw the "list index out of range" Error when no matches are found in the following example?

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import difflib

df1 = DataFrame([[1,'034567','Foo'],
                 [2,'1cd2346','Bar']], 
                columns=['ID','Unit','Name'])
df2 = DataFrame([['SellTEST','0ab1234567'],
                 ['superVAR','1ab2345']], 
                columns=['Seller', 'Unit'])

df2['Unit'] = df2['Unit'].apply(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, df1['Unit'])[0])

df1.merge(df2)
```

I get that the value in df1 is way off - but I wouldn't expect this to error like it does, I would expect it to simply not match.

Comment: I think you are answering your own question... `difflib` is returning no close matches, which is an empty list. Then you blindly deference it, assuming there is a match, and there isn't. your lambda, instead of just deferencing `[0]`, needs to check for a length first. What do you want to be there for no matches?

Answer (score 1):

`get_close_matches` *does* simply not match - the list returned by `difflib.get_close_matches` is empty, and then you try and access the first element of it, which throws  the `IndexError`.

If you wanted to replace an element where there are no matches with `None`, you could use this code instead, which utilises the fact that an empty list is falsey to replace a falsey value with `None`:

```
df2['Unit'] = df2['Unit'].apply(lambda x: (difflib.get_close_matches(x, df1['Unit'])[:1] or [None])[0])
```